# where to apply ApplicationContextAware

Tags: java, spring

I have a Service class which is a spring bean and I want to use this Service class inside a class (Class A) which is not a spring bean.

Where exactly should I implement ApplicationContextAware ?

Following is my code

```
   @Service("sharedListsService")
   public class  SharedListsService
   {

   }

   public class A
   {
      // I want to call my service class methods here
   }
```

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648635/calling-a-spring-service-class-from-another

Comment: This above link does not use ApplicationContextAware. I have to use ApplicationContextAware .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it is a best solution but you can refactor your `A` class like following:

```
public class A {
    private SharedListsService sharedListsService;

    public void setSharedListsService(SharedListsService sharedListsService) {
        this.sharedListsService = sharedListsService;
    }
}
```

and then inject spring bean when you create an A class instance (for example):

```
SharedListsService sharedListsService = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(appContext).getBean(SharedListsService.class);

A a = new A();
a.setSharedListsService(sharedListsService);
```

Comment: I actually want to call a method from Service class inside my A class

Answer (score 1):

[ApplicationContextAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)  applies to spring beans only.
It will inject application context into a bean. That's why you cannot directly use it to get instance of SharedListsService into "A".
You need a bean, possibly a [factory](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean) for "A" to wire that for you.